# How to get windows username in angular 8

Tags: html, angular, windows, typescript

I want to get my Windows username in my angular 8 application's typeScript, is this possible? I found something like this:

```
let user = new ActiveXObject("WSCRIPT.Network");
console.log(user.UserName.toLowerCase());
```

When I tried the code, I got 'error TS2340: Can not find the name ActiveXObject'

Is there a way of getting Windows or System username in angular application, if yes, how can one go about the coding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try opening the `tsconfig.json` file and adding the `"scripthost"` as an element of the `"lib"` section:

```
"lib": [
   "es2018",
   ...
   "scripthost"
]
```

That should make sure the correct library for ActiveXObject is loaded.
I found a couple of references to this a possible fix online. Here is one [article](https://medium.com/@braelynnn/using-phaser-in-an-angular-8-component-53644a2280e3)

Comment: I added the scripthost in my .json file, the TS2304 error fixed but now I got 'ActiveXObject is not defined'. Do you have an idea on how to go about this?

Comment: @Pleasure were you able to get it working in Chrome ?